# Configure theme admin in frontend

Tags: module, theme

I tryed to making a theme options for change font size and family from backend but in frontend i don't see changes. I see the option (font size and font family ) on adminpanel. I have done the file system.xml whit section, file font.php in Model ( with all options ). After this i added this code to header.phtml ( without dot ):

```
<?php echo   Mage::getStoreConfig(themeadmin/general/options,Mage::app()getStore()); ?>
```

If i make changes on admin, i don't see changes on frontend. I need to put this code into a div with text?

Answer (score 1):

You should write correct php:

```
Mage::getStoreConfig('themeadmin/general/options');
```

You can omit `Mage::app()getStore()`, because default is the current store.

You didn't post your XML but I would expect `font_size` or `font_family` in the path.

To know where your data is saved, you can either [understand how system.xml works](http://alanstorm.com/custom_magento_system_configuration) or you can check `core_config_data` database table where your options are saved.